# Measure theory converge in measure

Tags: measure-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $\mu$ be finite measure on $(E,\beta)$ and f, f_n two measurable functions from E to $\Re$ such that $f_n$ converge in measure to f
and g is apllication from $\Re$ to $\Re$

Suppose that g is a continuous function .
proof that
$\forall$ k $\in$ $N^*$ and $\delta$ > 0
$\exists$ $\eta$ $\in$ ]0 1[ such that for every n $\in$ N

{|$g\circ f_n - g\circ f|\geq \delta$} $\subset$
{$|f_n - f| \geq \eta$}$\cup${|f|>k}

Deduce that $g\circ f_n$ converges in measure to $ g\circ f$

Comment: Please show your attempt.

Comment: I don't know how to start

Answer (score 0):

There is a Corollary in Chapter 4 of Royden's "Real Analysis" saying that $f_{n}\to f$ in measure if and only if every subsequence of $f_{n}$ has in turn a subsequence
$f_{n_{k}}\to f$ almost everywhere. So , assume that $gof_{n_{k}}$ is a subsequence of $gof_{n}$. Then $f_{n_{k}}$ is a subsequence of $f_{n}$ and by the Corollary there is a further subsequence $f_{n_{k},m}\to f$ on a set E of full measure (ie almost everywhere). On the set E we have by continuity of g that $ gof_{n_{k},m}(x)\to gof(x)$. Therefore $gof_{n_{k},m}\to gof$ almost everywhere. Thus the condition of the Corollary is satisfied and hence $gof_{n}\to gof$ in measure!!

Answer (score 0):

I think of this idea
Part one
Let the set $S_k$ =[-k-1,k+1] then $S_k$ is compact and so g is uniformly continuous
on $S_k$.
Let $L_k$ ={x: |f(x)|$\leq$k}.
Then from the uniformly continuous of g $\exists$ $\eta_0$ such that

$\forall \delta$ $\forall$ x,y $\in$ $S_k$ |x-y|<$\eta_0$ $\rightarrow$ |g(x)-g(y)| <$\delta$

Then for $\eta = min(\eta_0,1)$
$\forall$ x$\in$ $L_k$
|f_n(x)-f(x)|< $\eta$ $\rightarrow$ $f_n(x)$
and f(x) $\in$ $S_k$ and thus
$|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\eta \rightarrow$
|g(f_n(x))-g(f(x))|<$\delta$

Then by
|g(f_n(x))-g(f(x))|$\geq \delta$ $\rightarrow$ $|f_n(x)-f(x)|\geq \eta $ or |f(x)|>k
Part two
Taking the limit of the measure in both sides
So
$\mu$($|g\circ f_n - g\circ f|> \delta$)< $\mu(|f_n - f|>\eta)$ + $\mu(|f|>k)$
Implise
$lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}$ $\mu$($|g\circ f_n - g\circ f|> \delta$)<
$\mu$(|f|>k) for all k then taking k to infinity and because the measure is finite so the limit can pass throw and then we get $\mu(|f|>\infty)$ = 0